# How do I create and use a junction table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following data:

1. A post called `Hello` has categories `greet`
2. Another post called `Hola` has categories `greet, international`

My schema is:

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "categories", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "posts_categories", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "post_id"
  t.integer  "category_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

After reading the Rails guide, the most suitable relationship for the above seems to be:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

My junction table also seems to have a primary key.  I think I need to get rid of it.

1. What's the initial migration command to generate a junction table in Rails?
2. What's the best course of action, should I drop `posts_categories` and re-create it or just drop the primary key column?
3. Does the junction table have a corresponding model? I have used `scaffold` to generate the junction table code, should I get rid of the extra code?

Assuming all the above has been fixed and is working properly, how do I query all posts and display them along with their named categories in the view.  For example:

```
Post #1 - hello, categories: greet
Post #2 - hola, categories: greet, international
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might want to check out [this web page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) from the rails API doc.

1. the easiest way to generate a junction table is `"script/generate model categories_posts category_id:integer post_id:integer"`.  Note that the class names should be in alphabetical order.  I'm fairly indifferent to the whole primary key thing, but if it becomes an issue, you can generate a migration to drop like 'script/generate DropPostsCategoriesIdFromPostsCategories posts_categories_id:integer' (make sure this migration file does what you want, i haven't tested it and what it does may vary by your version of rails) and then do `rake db:migrate`. to change the DB.
2. for the class name you're using, you could use:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :categories, :through => :posts_categories
end
```

has_many through lets you specify the names of the join/junction table.  or you could drop the table and regenerate it with the right name.

3. (should be #3) yeah, just generate a model for a join class, don't do the entire scaffold.  (see above)

to find all posts, do something like `@posts = Post.find(:all)`

to print out the categories, do something like

```
@posts.each do | post |
   print post.name, "\n"
   @posts.categories.each do | cat |
        print "\t", cat.name, "\n"
   end
end
```

in actual rails code, you'd want to do that in the view, this is more of a console output-type thing.